# Setting SQL session variables every time modules are installed or updated?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 using a Digital Ocean Managed Database(DO).  The issue is that DO does not allow tables to be created without a primary key(via global `sql_require_primary_key=1`).  They do allow this to be set locally via `SET @@local.sql_require_primary_key = 0;`, but I cannot think of a way to set this before any/all `CREATE TABLE ...` run during each and every setup.  I was able to install Magento via a SQL import and setting the session variable, but now even extensions that create tables are erroring out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out the /app/etc/env.php file has an `initStatements` setting where these can be set.  My specific need was added like so

```
'db' => [
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8; SET @@local.sql_require_primary_key = OFF;'
        ]
    ]
]
```